# How make accordeon using siblings

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle, siblings

I have accordeon and some jquery script

```
    $(function () {
        $('.step-content').slideToggle(0);
        $('.step-title').click(function () {
            $(this).next('.step-content').slideToggle(100);
            $(this).children('.toggle-btn-down').toggleClass('toggle-btn-up');
        });
    });
```

i want to fold not active items

this is my example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/spJWy/

Comment: Can you provide your HTML markup too?

Comment: yes, sorry.. im add url to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `slideToggle`, `hasClass`, `toggleClass`, `not` and `hide` to match all other elements and hide them accordingly.

Code:

```
 $(function () {
     $('.step-content').slideToggle(0);
     $('.step-title').click(function () {
         var $stepContent=$(this).children('.step-content');
         var $stepIcon=$(this).children('.toggle-icon');
         $stepContent.slideToggle(100);
         if ($stepIcon.hasClass('toggle-btn-down')){
             $('.step-content').not($stepContent).hide(100)
             $('.toggle-icon').not($stepIcon).addClass('toggle-btn-down').removeClass('toggle-btn-up');
         }
         $stepIcon.toggleClass('toggle-btn-up toggle-btn-down');
     });
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RyXp2/